# Django raw sql insert: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: sql, django

I have the following model:

```
class test_data_urls(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
```

I want to insert a value into mysql:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
url = "hiya"
cursor.execute("insert into my_table(url) values (%s)", (url))
```

I get an error:
    'str' object has no attribute 'items'

This works:

```
 cursor.execute("insert into my_table(url) values ('test')")
```

but I want to do it with %s. To me, it looks exactly like how I have always done this, so what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `[` and `]` instead of `(` and `)`:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
url = "hiya"
cursor.execute("insert into my_table(url) values (%s)", [url])
```

---

The reason that (url) does not work is because it's not a tuple, it's a single string. (url,) would be a tuple.

Comment: That worked, thanks. I'll do it that way. I don't get it, though; I'm looking at some other code that I just ran and there is works with the parentheses.

Comment: I've seen the info here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/ All examples add []

Comment: The reason is that `(url)` is not a tuple, it's a single string. `(url,)` would be a tuple.